# Can't see Memory Window in VS2005

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005

In VS2005 you should be able to click Debug->Windows->Memory->Memory<1,2,3, or 4>. However in my VS there is no memory item in the Debug->Windows drop-down. Has anyone ever experienced this before or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the visual settings are simply hiding the memory window.  I know at least one of the VB.Net profiles does this.  You can get it to display be executing the following command from the Command window while the debugger is running

> Debug.Memory1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a free version of VS?